# Mac window doesn't open after closing

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow

I'm developing a Mac App using Xcode (Objective C). The app launches and works fine, but when I click the red close button on the top left, an issue arises. The app closes as expected, but the default OS X behaviour is to keep the app running in the background (icon in bottom bar). This isn't a problem per se, but when I click the app icon again. The app doesn't open anymore. I have to right click, quit the app and open it again.

I'm sure it's easy fix, but I don't know where to begin. Did anyone experience this issue? Thanks!

Comment: "closes as expected", I would expect, by default, for the window to close, but not the app.  The latter is easily arranged, however (see `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed`).  Sounds like you might be having issues with window management within your app.

Comment: Yes, the window closes, but not the app. The problem is that I can't reopen the window by clicking the icon. I have to quit the app and open it again.

Comment: I would expect a new window to be opened by the user selecting `File` > `New` and not by clicking the dock icon.

Comment: The default app behaviour is to close the window, but there is no way to open it again (no new window option in the menu). Is there any way to either quit the app when closing the window or just hiding the window when clicking the closing button, and showing it again when clicking the app icon?

Comment: Well you need to do work to provide that functionality.  I believe if you use the default Xcode document-based app template then that comes for free.  The non-document-based app template's window cannot be closed as far as I remember, and that is another option.

Comment: You say `"The app closes as expected, ..."`, but I think you mean to say `"The window closes as expected, ..."`. (Since later on you talk about the app which is still running...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this method to the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag
{
    [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    return NO;
}
```